# Variable sample upper value in R

Tags: r, random

I have the following matrix

```
m <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 5, 7, 9, 3, 7), nrow=5, ncol=2,) 
colnames(x) = c("Y","Z")
m <-data.frame(m)
```

I am trying to create a random number in each row where the upper limit is a number based on a variable value (in this case 1*Y based on each row's value for for Z)

I currently have:

```
 samp<-function(x){
    sample(0:1,1,replace = TRUE)}

    x$randoms <- apply(m,1,samp)
```

which work works well applying the sample function independently to each row, but I always get an error when I try to alter the x in sample. I thought I could do something like this:

```
samp<-function(x){
        sample(0:m$Z,1,replace = TRUE)}

        x$randoms <- apply(m,1,samp)
```

but I guess that was wishful thinking.

Ultimately I want the result:

```
 Y Z randoms
 2 5       4
 4 7       7
 3 9       3
 5 3       1
 1 7       6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your example produces errors - you've got a `y` in there - what is it? same as `x`? Also, you say you want to sample from 0 to `x$Y`, but your desired output seems to use `x$Z` instead (e.g. the last row, your `Y` column is only 1 so you should sample from 0:1, but you have 6 for your `randoms`). Please clarify.

Comment: sloppy quick example by me - correct my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will sample from 0 to `x$Y` for each row, and store the result in `randoms`:

```
x$randoms <- sapply(x$Y + 1, sample, 1) - 1
```

Explanation:

The `sapply` takes each value in `x$Y` separately (let's call this `y`), and calls `sample(y + 1, 1)` on it.

Note that (e.g.) `sample(y+1, 1)` will sample 1 random integer from the range `1:(y+1)`. Since you want a number from 0 to `y` rather than 1 to `y + 1`, we subtract 1 at the end.

Also, just pointing out - no need for `replace=T` here because you are only sampling one value anyway, so it doesn't matter whether it gets replaced or not.

Comment: A great guess based on the OP's poor problem statement and choice of variables.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee nailed it, even with my extremely sloppy example! I had a feeling it was something simple - this is what happens when you stare at the screen too long...

Answer (score 1):

Based on @mathematical.coffee suggestion and my edited example this is the slick final result:

```
m <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 5, 7, 9, 3, 7), nrow=5, ncol=2,) 
 colnames(m) = c("Y","Z")
m <-data.frame(m) 

samp<-function(x){
sample(Z + 1, 1)}

m$randoms <- sapply(m$Z + 1, sample, 1) - 1
```

Comment: There is no need to repost your example along with someone else's answer as your own asnwer, unless you are offering something new on that answer.